# Getting NaN in Javascript With Simple Calculation

Tags: javascript, nan

```
<script>
function runCals() {
   var milesRun = document.getElementById("runDist")
   var runCals = Number(milesRun) * 96
   document.getElementById("cals").innerHTML = runCals
}

</script>
```

I am getting NaN and I do not understand why. I visited many stack questions but none I found had my specific problem.

Why am I getting NaN and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you get if you do console.log(Number(milesRun))?

Comment: My computer has inspect element blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`milesRun` is not a number, it's a DOM node, so you can't convert it to a number. If it's an input box just add `.value` to the end of the selector to extract the value inputted into it. e.g.

```
function runCals() {
   var milesRun = document.getElementById("runDist").value
   var runCals = Number(milesRun) * 96
   document.getElementById("cals").innerHTML = runCals
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will accept this answer once this site enables me to, in 12 minutes.

Comment: There’s some wrong terminology here. `milesRun` _is_ a value. It’s just an object, instead of the intended number.

Comment: Lol no worries, we all make silly mistakes sometimes.

Comment: @Xufox From Google Dictionary "Value" the numerical amount denoted by an algebraic term; a magnitude, quantity, or number. But you're right in that it might be a bit confusing so I added "number" value. It wasn't wrong terminology.

Comment: @joe-tom In JavaScript terms, all of those things are values. There’s a distinction of primitive values, but objects are values, too.

Comment: @Xufox, in terms of this question given that I referenced that it was a Node from the DOM it was implied that this was not a "numerical" value. If you didn't catch that I understand, but there's no reason to downvote me (if that was you).

Comment: I didn’t vote on your post at all.